# Which keylogger is best for being undetectable by task manager?

Tags: windows, keylogger, spyware

I've been in search of a keylogger that, even during its trial period, is undetectable by task manager, that is, when it's running, you can't see the process in task manager. I've downloaded a bunch of them and the one that finally works is refog keylogger but the big problem with it is that it doesn't start on windows startup. So, is there a keylogger or any spy software that, when running, does not show in task manager. The ones I've downloaded and tried are:
Spytech, om spy, real pc spy, and spyrix.

Comment: There have been a few keylogger questions recently.  Same point to be made here. Be absolutely certain that using on eis legal in your jurisdiction. Because as soon as you make use of whatever you capture, someone (a very angry someone) is likely to figure what you did and report it to the police if illegal.

Comment: I have files on my laptop that are hidden from my brother but I realise has been sending those files to his laptop. I wanna figure out how. That's all I need the keylogger for

Comment: Might still be illegal, but I doubt if it will get you arrested :-)  Your files are not "hidden" well enough. Encrypt them with a good password. I have a brother too & feel your pain :-)

Comment: Apparently, all I needed to do was tell him to stop sending the videos. So now, the matter has been resolved. Thanks so much for your contributions

Comment: I would still recommend encrypting any sensitive data.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment:

Leaving aside any legal, *(which depends on the jurisdiction of the parties involved)* and moral issues as to why you need this you can purchase hardware key loggers which physically interpose between the keyboard and the computer and are undetectable by task manager.

It is also worth remembering that any such software, *or hardware*, solution **may** not only be reporting to you - if it is installed on a network connected computer then keystrokes could be being sent anywhere in the world.